# The total cost of Tution 4 years from now

Tags: java

I am doing practice problem from a  textbook, but I can not figure out how to do this efficiently with a `for` loop.

***Question:** The college tuition this year is $10000, and it increases by 5% every year. Write a program to display the total cost of 4 years worth of tuition starting ten years from now.*

This is what I came up with so far.

```
public class ComputeFutureTuition {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double baseTuition = 10000;
        final double RATE = 1.05;

        System.out.println("The total cost of 4 years tution");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            // keep track of the next 4 year's tuition
            double fourYearTuition = 0;

            fourYearTuition = baseTuition + (baseTuition * RATE) 
                + (baseTuition * RATE * RATE) + (baseTuition * RATE * RATE * RATE);

            System.out.printf("%2d yrs from now: $%5.2f\n", 
                    (i + 1), fourYearTuition);
            // Increase the tuition by 5%
            baseTuition = baseTuition * 1.05;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this question by calculating each year's tuition only once? Right now my solution is throwing out the result at each iteration. (No `arrayList` or `class` yet, just the basics are introduced).

Desire output:

```
The total cost of 4 years tution
 1 yrs from now: $43101.25
 2 yrs from now: $45256.31
 3 yrs from now: $47519.13
 4 yrs from now: $49895.08
 5 yrs from now: $52389.84
 6 yrs from now: $55009.33
 7 yrs from now: $57759.80
 8 yrs from now: $60647.79
 9 yrs from now: $63680.18
10 yrs from now: $66864.19
```

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? What is your specific *code* question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need an outer loop: to get the tuition ten years from now, multiply today's tuition by `pow(RATE, 10)`; that would be your new `baseTuition` 10 years from now.

After that, you can run a single loop to add four numbers - `baseTuition`, `baseTuition*RATE`, `baseTuition*RATE*RATE`, and `baseTuition*RATE*RATE*RATE`.  However, that is not necessary either: all you need is calculating a sum of geometric series [using the well-known formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula):

```
double res = pow(RATE, 10) * (1-pow(RATE, 4)) / (1 - RATE);
```

Comment: Knowing math makes everything easier.

Comment: I am thinking along the line of keeping track of Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4. And then updating the Y1 and Y4 at each iteration. (So each year is only calculated once).

Answer (score 1):

The math for calculating the compounding can be expressed as this:

[image]

So the base tuition ten years from now will be

`10000*Math.pow(1.05,10)` or `16288.94627`.  You could then multiply that by 1.05 to get the 11th year, and again to get the 12th and so on.  Add each of those values up and you should get your answer.

Since this appears to be a homework problem, I am not going to give you the code to solve it.